# Convert line shapefile to raster, value=total length of lines within cell

Tags: raster, r, line, rasterization

I have a line shapefile representing a road network. I wish to rasterize this data, with the resulting values in the raster showing the total length of the lines that fall within the raster cell.

The data is in the British National Grid projection so the units will be meters.

Ideally I would like to perform this operation using `R`, and i'm guessing that the `rasterize` function from the `raster` package would play a part in achieving this, I just can't work out what the function applied should be.

Comment: Maybe `vignette('over', package = 'sp')` might help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Following a [recent question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112590/convert-esri-shapefile-to-raster-using-r-biggest-polygon-area-to-raster-cell-v/112852#112852), you may want to make use of the functionalities offered by the **rgeos** package to solve your problem. For reasons of reproducibility, I downloaded a shapefile of Tanzanian roads from [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) and put it in my current working directory. For the upcoming tasks, you will need three packages:

- **rgdal** for general spatial data handling
- **raster** for rasterization of the shapefile data
- **rgeos** to check intersection of roads with raster template and calculate road lengths

Consequently, your first lines of could should look like this:

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
```

After that, you need to import the shapefile data. Note that DIVA-GIS shapefiles are distributed in EPSG:4326, so I will project the shapefile to EPSG:21037 (UTM 37S) to deal with meters rather than degrees.

```
roads <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "TZA_roads")
roads_utm <- spTransform(roads, CRS("+init=epsg:21037"))
```

For subsequent rasterization, you will need a raster template that covers the spatial extent of your shapefile. The raster template consists of 10 rows and 10 columns by default, thus avoiding too extensive computation times.

```
roads_utm_rst <- raster(extent(roads_utm), crs = projection(roads_utm))
```

Now that the template is set up, loop through all cells of the raster (that currently consists of NA values only). By assigning a value of '1' to the current cell and subsequently executing `rasterToPolygons`, the resulting shapefile 'tmp_shp' automatically holds the extent of the currently processed pixel. `gIntersects` detects whether this extent overlaps with roads. If not, the function will return a value of '0'. Otherwise, the road shapefile is cropped by the current cell and the total length of 'SpatialLines' within that cell is being calculated using `gLength`.

```
lengths <- sapply(1:ncell(roads_utm_rst), function(i) {
  tmp_rst <- roads_utm_rst
  tmp_rst[i] <- 1
  tmp_shp <- rasterToPolygons(tmp_rst)

  if (gIntersects(roads_utm, tmp_shp)) {
    roads_utm_crp <- crop(roads_utm, tmp_shp)
    roads_utm_crp_length <- gLength(roads_utm_crp)
    return(roads_utm_crp_length)
  } else {
    return(0)
  }
})
```

Finally, you can insert the calculated lengths (which are converted to kilometers) into the raster template and visually verify your results.

```
roads_utm_rst[] <- lengths / 1000

library(RColorBrewer)
spplot(roads_utm_rst, scales = list(draw = TRUE), xlab = "x", ylab = "y", 
       col.regions = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "YlOrRd")), 
       sp.layout = list("sp.lines", roads_utm), 
       par.settings = list(fontsize = list(text = 15)), at = seq(0, 1800, 200))
```

[image: lines2raster]

Comment: This is awesome! I changed `sapply()` to `pbsapply()` and used the cluster argument `cl = detectCores()-1`. Now I'm able to run this example in parallel!

Answer (score 16):

You can now do this with `terra::rasterizeGeom`

Example data:

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
r <- rast(v)
```

Solution:

```
x <- rasterizeGeom(v, r, "length")    
plot(x); lines(v)
```

---

The below is a solution with the older spatial packages. It is based on Jeffrey Evans' answer, but this one is much faster as it does not use rasterize

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

roads <- shapefile("TZA_roads.shp")
roads <- spTransform(roads, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=37 +south +datum=WGS84"))
rs <- raster(extent(roads), crs=projection(roads))
rs[] <- 1:ncell(rs)

# Intersect lines with raster "polygons" and add length to new lines segments
rsp <- rasterToPolygons(rs)
rp <- intersect(roads, rsp)
rp$length <- gLength(rp, byid=TRUE) / 1000
x <- tapply(rp$length, rp$layer, sum)
r <- raster(rs)
r[as.integer(names(x))] <- x
```

Comment: Seems the most efficient and elegant method of those listed. Also, hadn't seen `raster::intersect()`  before, I like that it combines the attributes of the intersected features, unlike `rgeos::gIntersection()`.

Comment: +1 always nice seeing more efficient solutions!

Comment: @RobertH, I tried using this solution for another problem, where I want to do the same as asked in this thread, but with a very large shapefile of roads (for an entire continent). It seems to have worked, but when I try to do the figure as done by @ fdetsch, I do not  get a contiguous grid but just a few colored squares in the picture (see in http://tinypic.com/r/20hu87k/9).

Comment: And by most efficient... with my sample dataset: run time 0.6sec for this solution vs. 8.25sec for the most upvotes solution.

Comment: For my use case it takes to much memory.

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another approach. It deviates from those already given by using the `spatstat` package. As far as I can tell, this package has its own version of spatial objects (e.g. `im` vs. `raster` objects), but the `maptools` package allows conversion back and forth between `spatstat` objects and standard spatial objects.

This approach is taken from [this R-sig-Geo post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2015-March/022483.html).

```
require(sp)
require(raster)
require(rgdal)
require(spatstat)
require(maptools)
require(RColorBrewer)

# Load data and transform to UTM
roads <- shapefile('data/TZA_roads.shp')
roadsUTM <- spTransform(roads, CRS("+init=epsg:21037"))

# Need to convert to a line segment pattern object with maptools
roadsPSP <- as.psp(as(roadsUTM, 'SpatialLines'))

# Calculate lengths per cell
roadLengthIM <- pixellate.psp(roadsUTM, dimyx=10)

# Convert pixel image to raster in km
roadLength <- raster(dtanz / 1000, crs=projection(roadsUTM))

# Plot
spplot(rtanz, scales = list(draw=TRUE), xlab="x", ylab="y", 
       col.regions=colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "YlOrRd")), 
       sp.layout=list("sp.lines", roadsUTM), 
       par.settings=list(fontsize=list(text=15)), at=seq(0, 1800, 200))
```

[image: Imgur]

The slowest bit is converting the roads from `SpatialLines` to a Line Segment Pattern (i.e. `spatstat::psp`). Once that's done the actual length calculation parts is quite quick, even for much higher resolutions. For example, on my old 2009 MacBook:

```
system.time(pixellate(tanzpsp, dimyx=10))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.007   0.001   0.007

system.time(pixellate(tanzpsp, dimyx=1000))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.146   0.032   0.178
```

Comment: Hmmmm...I sure wish those axes weren't in scientific notation. Anyone have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: You can modify the global R settings and turn off notation using: options(scipen=999)) however, I do not know if lattice will honor the global environment settings.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a for loop. Just intersect everything at once and then add line lengths to the new line segments using the "SpatialLinesLengths" function in sp. Then, using the raster package rasterize function with the fun=sum argument you can create a raster with the sum of the line length(s) intersecting each cell. Using the above answer and associated data here is code that will generate the same results.

```
require(rgdal)
require(raster)
require(sp)
require(rgeos)

setwd("D:/TEST/RDSUM")
roads <- readOGR(getwd(), "TZA_roads")
  roads <- spTransform(roads, CRS("+init=epsg:21037"))
    rrst <- raster(extent(roads), crs=projection(roads))

# Intersect lines with raster "polygons" and add length to new lines segments
rrst.poly <- rasterToPolygons(rrst)
  rp <- gIntersection(roads, rrst.poly, byid=TRUE)
    rp <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(rp, data.frame(row.names=sapply(slot(rp, "lines"), 
                               function(x) slot(x, "ID")), ID=1:length(rp), 
                               length=SpatialLinesLengths(rp)/1000) ) 

# Rasterize using sum of intersected lines                            
rd.rst <- rasterize(rp, rrst, field="length", fun="sum")

# Plot results
require(RColorBrewer)
spplot(rd.rst, scales = list(draw=TRUE), xlab="x", ylab="y", 
       col.regions=colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "YlOrRd")), 
       sp.layout=list("sp.lines", rp), 
       par.settings=list(fontsize=list(text=15)), at=seq(0, 1800, 200))
```

Comment: First time I see `SpatialLinesLengths`. Guess it is never too late to learn, thank you (: `rasterize` takes quite long, though (7 times longer than the upper approach on my machine).

Comment: I did notice that rasterize was being slow. However, for large problems a for loop is going to really slow things down and I think that your will see a much more optimized solution with rasterize. Besides the developer of the raster package is striving to make every release more optimized and faster.

Comment: One potential issue I found with this technique is that the `rasterize()` function includes all lines that *touch* a given cell. This results in line segment lengths being counted twice in some cases: once in the cell they're supposed to and once in the adjacent cell that the line endpoint just touches.

Comment: Yes, but "rp" is the object that is being rasterized which it the intersection of polygons and points.

Answer (score 1):

Let me present you the package [vein](https://www.geosci-model-dev.net/11/2209/2018/) with several functions to work spatial lines and imports [sf](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=sf) and [data.table](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=data.table)

```
library(vein)
library(sf)
library(cptcity)
data(net)
netsf <- st_as_sf(net) #Convert Spatial to sf
netsf <- st_transform(netsf, 31983) # Project data
netsf$length_m  <- st_length(netsf)
netsf <- netsf[, "length_m"]
g <- make_grid(netsf, width = 1000) #Creat grid of 1000m spacing with columns id for each feature
# Number of lon points: 12
# Number of lat points: 11

gnet <- emis_grid(netsf, g)
plot(gnet["length_m"])

sf_to_raster <- function(x, column, ncol, nrow){
  x <- sf::as_Spatial(x)
  r <- raster::raster(ncol = ncol, nrow = nrow)
  raster::extent(r) <- raster::extent(x)
  r <- raster::rasterize(x, r, column)
  return(r)
}

rr <- sf_to_raster(gnet, "length_m", 12, 11)
spplot(rr, sp.layout = list("sp.lines", as_Spatial(netsf)),
       col.regions = cpt(), scales = list(draw = T))
spplot(rr, sp.layout = list("sp.lines", as_Spatial(netsf)),
       col.regions = cpt(pal = 5176), scales = list(draw = T))
spplot(rr, sp.layout = list("sp.lines", as_Spatial(netsf)),
       col.regions = lucky(), scales = list(draw = T))
# Colour gradient: neota_flor_apple_green, number: 6165
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -4):

This may sound a bit naive but if it is a road system then select the roads and save to a clip board then look find a tool that allows you to add a buffer to the clipboard set it to the legal width of the road ie 3 meters +/- remember that the buffer is from center line to edge * 2  i for each side so a 3 meter buffer is actually a 6 meter road from side to side.

Comment: What does road width have to do with road length. This answer does not address the question.