# What's the most efficient way to calculate line length per raster cell in R?

Tags: raster, r, rasterization, terra, stars

#### Problem

I'm looking for an efficient, memory friendly to **calculate total line (vector data) length per raster cell**.

The question of line length per cell has already been posed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119993/convert-line-shapefile-to-raster-value-total-length-of-lines-within-cell) in 2014 and a few solutions were proposed. I implemented the fastest solution proposed there (kudos to [Robert Hijmans](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/8993/robert-hijmans)) and updated it a little bit to use `sf` instead of `rgeos` (see the example below).

My problem is, that my real life data contains a lot of lines (around 40 000) and a fine regular raster (around 700 000 cells), so I ran into the following error:

```
Error in RGEOSBinPredFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, func) :
  rgeos_binpredfunc_prepared: maximum returned dense matrix size exceeded
```

I have around 200GB RAM available for this task...

#### Possible Solutions

1. I guess an efficient solution via [`terra::intersect`](https://rdrr.io/github/rspatial/terra/man/intersect.html) or [`stars::st_intersects`](https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/reference/st_intersects.stars.html) is possible, but I didn't manage to make them work. Maybe they could replace [`raster::intersect`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.5-15/topics/intersect). Btw, I'm a big fan of both `stars` and `terra` packages...
2. Some clever way to do it in chunks? Maybe chop up the raster into multiple small rasters and loop through these, combine the resulting small rasters into a big one after that.
3. Getting somehow rid of step `3.) Make Polygons from raster` could help a lot, too.

Combining the lines into one via `sf::st_combine` did not make it faster...

#### Example

```
library("raster")
library("sf")
library("stars") # not used, but potentially helpful for solution
library("terra") # not used, but potentially helpful for solution


# 1.) Create "SpatialLines" object 
# (not sf Multilinestring, because raster::intersect() requires "Spatial")
nc_lines <- system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf") %>%
  st_read() %>%
  st_geometry() %>%
  st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") %>%
  as("Spatial")

# plot(nc_lines)

calc_lengths_per_cell <-  function(n_cell_rows = 10,
                                   n_cell_cols = 20) {

  # 2.) Create raster with n_cell_rows and n_cell_cols on extent of lines
  # (we need "id" layer for matching later, "values" layer will store the lengths later)
  nc_extent <- sf::st_bbox(nc_lines) %>%
    raster::extent()
  nc_raster <- raster::raster(
    nc_extent,
    nrows = n_cell_rows,
    ncols = n_cell_cols,
    crs = crs(nc_lines)
  )
  nc_raster$values <- rep(0, ncell(nc_raster)) # 
  nc_raster$id <- 1:ncell(nc_raster)
  
  # 3.) Make Polygons from raster
  # (I would love to get rid of this step)
  nc_poly <- raster::rasterToPolygons(nc_raster)
  
  # 4.) Calc intersections between lines and polys
  # (This is the computationally most expensive step.)
  nc_lines_intersec <- raster::intersect(nc_lines, nc_poly) %>%
    st_as_sf()
  
  # 5.) Calc lengths of line segments using sf and sum up lengths
  nc_lines_intersec$length <- sf::st_length(nc_lines_intersec)
  nc_line_lengths <- tapply(nc_lines_intersec$length,
                            nc_lines_intersec$id,
                            sum)
  
  # 6.) Assign lengths to raster cells by id
  # This will override "id" and "values" layer
  nc_raster[as.integer(names(nc_line_lengths))] <- nc_line_lengths
  # drop "id" layer, it's unnecessary
  nc_raster <- dropLayer(nc_raster, "id")
  
  
  # plot(nc_raster, main = "Line length per raster cell") +
  #  plot(nc_lines, add =T)
  
  return(nc_raster)
}
```

[image: plot]

```
system.time(calc_lengths_per_cell())
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.176   0.002   0.177 
system.time(calc_lengths_per_cell(100, 200))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  5.800   0.001   5.797
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a concise approach with 'terra'.

Example data:

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf")) |> as.lines()
r <- rast(v, ncol=20)
```

Solution:

```
x <- rasterizeGeom(v, r, "length")    
plot(x); lines(v)
```

I do not know how well it scales, but that can be fixed if need be.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't see `terra::rasterizeGeom()` because I was still on terra `terra_1.5-31`. What a game changer!

Comment: This solution worked like a charm for me  - on one core this solution took ~30h for my 40 000 lines on 700 000 raster cells. Memory use was suprisingly low, below 20GB...

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that is approximately twice faster using the same idea with `terra` and grouping with `data.table`. It is also likely less memory greedy.

```r
calc_lengths_per_cell2 <-  function(n_cell_rows = 10, n_cell_cols = 20) {
  
  nc_lines <- vect(nc_lines)
  nc_raster <- rast(ext(nc_lines), nrows = n_cell_rows, ncols = n_cell_cols, crs = crs(nc_lines))
  nc_raster <- init(nc_raster, "cell")
  nc_poly <- as.polygons(nc_raster)
  
  nc_lines_intersec <- intersect(nc_poly, nc_lines)
  nc_lines_intersec = st_as_sf(nc_lines_intersec)
  nc_lines_intersec$length = st_length(nc_lines_intersec)
  nc_lines_intersec = st_drop_geometry(nc_lines_intersec)

  data.table::setDT(nc_lines_intersec)
  lengths = nc_lines_intersec[, .(length = sum(length)), by = lyr.1]

  nc_raster = init(nc_raster, 0)
  nc_raster[lengths$lyr.1] = lengths$length
  return(nc_raster)
}
```

Then if it takes too much memory you can crop your lines in chunks of e.g. 100 km and loop through the chunks

Comment: Great solution, I’ll try it out on my real data and let u know…